# Reload page in framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

Framework7 version: Framework7 5.4.1

In index.html ('/') I have a login button, that open a login.html (/login/) page. This page send a request, and if it's logged correctly, I save de ID of user in localstorage and redirect to index.html  ('/').

In index, I modify the login button if the user are logged, hiding the button, and showing a message:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem('idCliente') == ''){
    $$('#login').html('<a class="col button button-fill menu color-green" href="/login/">Login</a>') 
  }else{    
    $$('#login').html('Welcome' + localStorage.getItem('nombreCliente')+'<a href="#" id="salir"> Salir</a>' ) 
  }
```

Redirection works, but not reload a Dom. Does not show the button or text. If I reload page (F5), show the wellcome + user message.

I try clear history, and other route options, but does not work.

```
  app.views.main.router.clearPreviousHistory()
  app.views.main.router.navigate('/', {
    reloadCurrent: true,
    ignoreCache: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use

```
pageAfterIn(e){
mainview.router.refreshPage();
//or
this.myrefreshFunction(); //call the refresh function which actually does the hiding 
thing
}
```